# Tensor algebra functor and coproducts.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $V_i$ be a family of vector spaces for $i\in I$. I'm trying to show that
$$T\bigoplus_{i\in I} V_i\cong \coprod_{i\in I}TV_i$$
where the RHS is the free product of algebras. My idea is to show that the LHS has the right universal property for the free product. The natural linear maps $V_i\rightarrow \bigoplus_{i\in I}V_i$ give algebra homomorphisms $TV_i \rightarrow T\bigoplus_{i\in I}V_i$, and I need to show these make the latter a free product of the $TV_i$s, but from here I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: What does represent your $T$?

Comment: Tensor algebra of a module (vector space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: What's the universal property of $T$ ?

Comment: Universal property of $T$ is that if $f:\bigoplus V_i\rightarrow A$ is a linear map into a $k$ algebra $A$, then there is a unique algebra homomorphism $f':T\bigoplus V_i\rightarrow A$ with the obvious commuting diagram. We need to show that this tensor algebra has the universal property of the free product of algebras.

Comment: Given $k$ algebra homomorphisms $f_{i}:TV_{i}\rightarrow A$, by the universal property of $T$, there are unique $k$ linear maps $g_{i}:V_{i}\rightarrow A$ such that $f_{i}=Tg_{i}$. Now by the universal property of direct sums, there is a unique $k$ linear map $g:\bigoplus_{i\in I}V_{i}\rightarrow A with g=\left(g_{i}\right)$. Again by the universal property of $T$, it follows that there is a unique $k$ algebra homomorphism $f=Tg:T\bigoplus_{i\in I}V_{i}\rightarrow A$ such that

Comment: $$\begin{array}{ccc}
TV_{i} & \rightarrow & A\\
\downarrow & \nearrow\\
T\bigoplus_{i\in I}V_{i}
\end{array}$$

commutes, so $T\bigoplus_{i\in I}V_{i}$ is a free product of the $TV_{i}$. Since free products are unique up to unique isomorphism, $T\bigoplus_{i\in I}V_{i}\cong\ast_{i\in I}TV_{i}$ are canonically isomorphic.

Comment: Is this this a correct proof?

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind. There is a more general statement about adjunctions but this is the gist of it

Comment: So, $T$ is right adjoint to the forgetful functor from $k\mathbb{-Alg}$ to $k\mathbb{-Vect}$, yes? Do you have a reference for the more general case of adjoint functors?

Comment: sorry, left adjoint

Comment: Yes, $T$ is indeed left adjoint. For a reference, you can look up any introduction to category theory that mentions adjoint functors and colimits, or type "left adjoint preserves colimits" on your search engine